# Addition of two matrix using loop

Tags: php, matrix

These are my two matrices in four arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
        )
)
```

How can I add up these matrices using loop?

Comment: What's your expected output? post it there?

Comment: 2 4
8 10
each index array add with same array index and same index value

Comment: both array are identical?

Comment: @ali Have you even tried something ?

Comment: @Rizier123 i tired doing through function but that doesn't worked

Comment: @anantkumarsingh yes

Comment: I puted the code. you can check

Comment: Please up-vote the answer also. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<?php 
$a1 = Array('0' => Array('0' => 1,'1' => 2),'1' => Array('0' => 4,'1' => 5));


$a2 = Array('0' => Array('0' => 1,'1' => 2),'1' => Array('0' => 4,'1' => 5));

$sumArray = array();

$result = array();
for($i=0; $i<=1; $i++) {
    for($j=0; $j<=1; $j++) {
        $result[$i][$j] = $a1[$i][$j] + $a2[$i][$j];
    }
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($result);
?>
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/75hoqi

Comment: *Why* should OP "Try this" ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$result = array();
for($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
    for($j=0; $j<=2; $j++) {
        $result[$i][$j] = $matrix1[$i][$j] + $matrix2[$i][$j];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot there were some problem i faced to adjust your code with my code but it worked...

Comment: well, of course it's not a copy paste solution, but the algorithm is good :)

Answer (score 0):

Go with `array_merge()` thats will merge the array into one

Comment: that would result in a 2x4 matrix instead of a sum of the elements